# Check if a generated key already exists in a file

Tags: python

so i am working on a script which generates random numbers and chars with uuid4.
Those generated keys are saved in a list and this list will be saved in a file called "already_used.txt".
My Question is:

How can i check my generated keys so that they are not in the already_used file, so i get unique keys.

```
    import uuid
    checklist_idfile = open('already_used.txt', 'a')
    already_used = []
    def checklist(string_length=9):
        count = 0
        while count < 20:
                count += 1
                checklist_random = str(uuid.uuid4())
                checklist_random = checklist_random.replace("-","")
                checklist_prefix = 'TEST_'
                id_checklist_random = checklist_prefix + checklist_random[0:string_length]
                print id_checklist_random
                already_used.append(id_checklist_random)
                checklist_idfile.write(id_checklist_random)
                checklist_idfile.write('\n')
```

a generated key looks like this: TEST_d1c23ba2f
Thank you very much!

Comment: It may be more convenient to use an actual database; sqlite3 could do nicely for this purpose.

Comment: But otherwise: read the file, split on newlines to get a list of strings, and test that your current key is not in the list of strings. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for keys in collection with `in` keyword:

```
if key in collection: do_something()
```

But beware, that if collection is `list`, it will take long time (for every key you check, you need to look trough almost whole list)

If you want to check for more keys at once, make a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#set) from the collection you want to compare against (set has constan, like so:

```
my_set = set(some_collection)

for key in keys:
    if key in my_set: do_something()
```

If you want to make set from file, do something like this: (assuming every key is at new line)

```
key_set = set([x.strip() for x in open("file.txt")])
```

Comment: Thank you. That really helped me solving this!

Comment: You really should close the file (ideally using a `with` statement). For a quick&dirty script that only uses one file and doesn't run for long and will probably only be used in CPython you can probably get away with it, but why bother when it's easy to do it the right way?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the question, you need to do something like :

```
with open("already_used.txt", "r") as used:
    already_used = {x.rstrip() for x in used}
if not some_key in already_used:
    doing somethig
    ...
```

Comment: You can simply iterate over the file. Then you don't have to strip the \n at the end. Also your indentation isn't right. The last three lines have to be in the with. And... you mist a letter in the  filename ;).

Comment: I recommend to use set instead of list to store already used keys because set doesn't store duplicates and "in" operator search in set much more faster then in list.

Comment: @VincentBeltman, My identation is right, because i need this "with" only for getting keys. Maybe this is not the best way.

Comment: @ValeriyG At least don't iterate over readlines. You should iterate over the file. The docs says _For reading lines from a file, you can loop over the file object. This is memory efficient, fast, and leads to simple code:_ https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Comment: Using `readlines()` is almost _never_ the best way. And using a list comprehension instead of a generator expression (or just a set comprehension, in this case) makes it even worse. You're essentially forcing Python to read the whole file into memory, then split the whole file into lines to store in a list in memory, then make another whole list of the stripped lines in memory, all just to create a set, when `already_used = {line.strip("\n") for line in used}` would start processing right away and avoid those three extra copies.

Comment: @abarnert, Edited. I hope this code is more correct.